# How to create rails session variable in action mailer?

Tags: ruby, session, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to create session variable in rails action mailer. While trying to create it's giving this error:

```
undefined local variable or method `session'
```

Please help if anyone knew solution.

Answer (score 0):

Session variables are not accessible in mailer.

You can access session variable through passing it as an argument.

```
YourMailer.mailer_method(session[:variable])
```

Comment: Sorry. I asked question wrongly. I want to create session variable inside mailer

Answer (score 0):

Just pass `current_user` to mailer's `method`. Mailers shouldn't access session variables and your `current_user` method depends on a `session variable`.

```
class MyMailer < ActionMailer::Base 
  def hello_email(user)
    @user = user
    # your hard stuff code whatever you wanted
  end
end
```

Now you can pass like this:

```
MyMailer.hello_email(current_user).deliver
```